# Querying a list of document id's in a firestore collection using react native firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm using react-native-firebase.  I have an array of document id's, and I need to query the associated documents by that array of id's.

I can do something like this:

```
firestore().collection('Foo').doc('myDocId').get();
```

to get a single document by id, but I don't want to iterate through the list and query each one individually.  However, I can't figure out how to query the collection by a list of document id's.  What I'd really like to do is something like:

```
firestore().collection('Foo').where('id','in',['myDocId1','myDocId2','myDocId3']).get();
```

however, this doesn't work (probably because 'id' is not actually a field in the documents, but rather the actual id of the document).  How do I write an equivalent query against the collection's document id's?